# Exporting Post ID, Post Title, Primary Category and Primary Category ID

Tags: database, mysql, export

Trying to export the following data from WordPress or directory through MYSQL query.

Post ID | Post Title | Post Content | Post Excerpt | Post Primary Category | Primary Category Term ID | Post categories | Category Term IDs

I have close to 115k posts in the database and close to 20k categories. Each post has multiple categories. So that's why I want one column to only have the primary category and the other column to list call categories.

I have tried all of the export plugins and the problem I run into is that I can not export "Primary Category Term ID" all in one file.  I can get all the other fields, expect for category ID in the same file...I can do it seperatly, but I am trying to get it all in one file.  It will save a lot of time.

I think the only way is to write a custom query that can export all the fields I need directly from mysql? is anyone here able to help me accomplish this?

Comment: How are you storing primary category? That's not something WordPress does on its own.

Comment: Is "Post Primary Category" a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no primary category key.  Usually, the first category is primary category by default.  So technically, the below are the only fields I will need.

Post ID | Post Title | Post Content | Post Excerpt | Post categories | Category Term IDs